# How to write custom form component in Ant Design Vue 2x?

Tags: antd, vuejs3, antdv, ant-design-vue

Ant Design Vue v1 provided a [documented example](https://www.antdv.com/components/form/#components-form-demo-customized-form-controls) for writing custom form components.

The same approach does not apply to version 2x.

How can a custom form component be implemented in AntDV 2x (vue 3) using [useForm](https://2x.antdv.com/components/form#components-form-demo-useForm-basic)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have figured this out. Previously your custom component needed to emit a `change` event:

```
methods: {
    handleChange(value) {
        this.emit('change', value);
    },
},
```

Having looked through the [source code](https://github.com/vueComponent/ant-design-vue/blob/21bf0a3a407d86ed046b4ba26de7b485a25fe511/components/select/index.tsx#L122) I learned that you also need to emit an `update:value` event as well:

```
methods: {
    handleChange(value) {
        this.emit('update:value', value);
        this.emit('change', value);
    },
},
```